# How do I reliably and silently maintain a connection to a remote fileserver on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, network-shares

Is there a way on Mac OS X 10.6 to force the OS to constantly attempt to connect to two separate file servers (On separate networks), maintaining the connection whenever possible?

Comment: Clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [connect to server](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4011?viewlocale=en_US) option to connect on log in, and it should maintain the connections when you move.

Comment: I'm already doing this, and unfortunately it only attempts the connection once, on login.

Comment: Then you'll have to reconnect. I don't think there is a method to continually attempt connections.